# MOUSE_DOWN and CLICK doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3

I have no ideas what is going on with my scripts but the MOUSE_DOWN AND CLICK event doesn't work. This is actionscript 3.0. The MOUSE_OVER IS working fine.

```
var myCell:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); 
myCell.graphics.clear();
myCell.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xfff000);//add yellow border
myCell.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100); 
myCell.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);//Fill with white
myCell.graphics.endFill(); 
myCell.x=300;
myCell.y=300;
myCell.name="testxx";
addChild(myCell);
myCell.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, fnMouseOver);
myCell.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fnMouseDown);
myCell.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fnMouseClick);


function fnMouseOver(evt:MouseEvent):void{
     trace("fnMouseOver"+evt.target.name);
}

function fnMouseDown(evt:MouseEvent):void{
     trace("fnMouseDown"+evt.target.name);
}

function fnMouseClick(evt:MouseEvent):void{
     trace("fnMouseClick"+evt.target.name);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the beginFill line above the drawRect

```
myCell.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);//Fill with white
myCell.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100); 
myCell.graphics.endFill();
```

You are essentially making a unfilled square otherwise.

Comment: thanks so much...that's easy..and sorry I can't accept the answer since i only have 14 reputations